# Drawing in a SurfaceView - canvas is null when calling holder.lockCanvas() in surfaceCreated()

Tags: android, drawing, surfaceview

I found a number of postings related to my question but none of them solved it. I'm trying it again. Hopefully my example is simple enough and I haven't forgotten anything crucial.
I have a `Fragment` and an inner class `CameraPreview`, derived from `SurfaceView` and implementing `SurfaceHolder.Callback`. What I want achieve is drawing on top of the camera preview that's displayed full-screen through `CameraPreview`.
I thought calling `canvas = holder.lockCanvas()` in `surfaceCreated()` would give me a `Canvas` for later drawing but `mCanvas` is always `null` if called after `setPreviewDisplay()` and `startPreview()`. If try to create the canvas before those two calls, I get a canvas but the app crashes immediately after.

Can someone explain why?

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {
    final static String TAG = "CameraFragment";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_native_camera, container, false);
        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        safeCameraOpenInView(view);

        return view;
    }

    public void safeCameraOpenInView(View view) {
        FrameLayout preview;
        Camera camera = null;

        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (camera != null) {
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), camera);
            if (view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview) != null) {
                preview = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
                preview.addView(mPreview);
                Log.d(TAG, "view found and set");
            } else Log.d(TAG, "FrameLayout is null");
        } 
    }

    class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        private Camera mCamera;
        private Canvas mCanvas;

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            // not sure the following is necessary
            setWillNotDraw(false);
            // do camera initialisation etc.
            mCamera = camera;
            // ...
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // here's the problem: If I initialize the canvas
            // before setting the preview display and start previewing
            // I get a canvas but the app crashes immediately after
            // If I request the canvas afterwards it's simply null
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startpreview();
            mCanvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            // mCanvas is null
            Log.d(TAG, "canvas: " + mCanvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Meanwhile I've read about the incompatibility between `holder.lockCanvas()` and `holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS)` - which I've happened to use for no special reason. But even after deleting the holder.setType line I keep getting null for the canvas.

Comment: After struggling with my original approach I've solved the problem by creating my own custom view class, overlaying the camera preview. That works nicely.